# JavaServlet project with gradle on Heroku didn't run

Tags: java, servlets, heroku, gradle

I uploaded JavaServlet project on Heroku. When I checked it on browser, it displayed  "Application Error" and didn't run.

According to the build log on Heroku, it seems that my project is built and deployed properly.

```
-----> Gradle app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done
-----> Building Gradle app...
-----> executing ./gradlew stage
       :clean UP-TO-DATE
       :copyToLib
       :compileJava
       :processResources NO-SOURCE
       :classes
       :war
       :stage

       BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 15s
       4 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 1 up-to-date
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 76.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v3
       https://rocky-sands-26639.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

I checked the runtime log using following command:

```
$heroku logs
```

Then I got following error log. How can I resolve this error?

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
```

I referred this page. I used gradle instead of maven.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku#using-webapp-runner-to-deploy-war-files

source code
https://github.com/fruitwater/heroku-servlet-gradle

Comment: One possibility: take a look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local to learn how to run your application on your own computer exactly as it will be run in Heroku. Your app *uploaded* okay, but uploading and actually successfully starting up are two very different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `--port $PORT` to your `Procfile`. It should look like this:

```
web: java -jar build/server/webapp-runner-*.jar --port $PORT build/libs/*.war
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I updated my Procfile like yours, but the error message didn't change.

Comment: what does the output of `heroku logs` show? What about `heroku ps`?

Comment: heroku logs  https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fruitwater/becd1ffeef0314dae022bf609f64e26f/raw/cd30c9bcdb72e4bdcbdc0416fe4f365caa2e921d/gistfile1.txt heroku ps https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fruitwater/bd91e547c9012726758622a4aa3f0e7a/raw/0db1e922f9036395a05ee57b153d1479afa00e37/heroku%2520ps

Comment: Run `heroku ps:scale web=1`